# How to control multi-factor-authentication (MFA) enrolment on Azure AD

Tags: entra-id

I would like to configure Azure AD MFA (cloud, not on-prem) such that it is only possible to enrol in MFA from trusted networks.

The MFA site is https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/proofup.aspx and has an application ID (017bbdfa-2b22-4cda-98dd-cd174b757f1b).

It seems sensible that I should be able to use conditional access to define which conditions this app can be used in. However that doesn't seem to work (perhaps this app is getting special treatment by Azure AD) and I can't find any documentation anywhere that describes how to do what I'm trying to do.

Has anyone done this successfully and can share how?